# reactjs conditional components - token error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to reactjs and looking to transform an old js file into a reactjs component. I've written the components out and I am trying to now append the same/similar if/else logic structure

but I am getting a -- Unexpected token error?

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html

so should the code look something like this - with lots of inline style conditional operators?

```
  return (
    <div>
      {isLoggedIn ? (
        <LogoutButton onClick={this.handleLogoutClick} />
      ) : (
        <LoginButton onClick={this.handleLoginClick} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
```

//old js

```
{if isset($interview)}

    {* First Information Section *}
    {* ******************************************** *}

    {assign  var="path" value="/views/video/video_first_section.tpl" }
    {include file="$base_path$path"}


    <div class="row show-for-small-only" style="height: 50px;"></div>

    {* Interview Tips Section *}
    {* ******************************************** *}

    {assign  var="path" value="/views/video/video_interview_tips.tpl" }
    {include file="$base_path$path"}

    {* Conference Calls Section *}
    {* ******************************************** *}

    {assign  var="path" value="/views/video/video_call.tpl" }
    {include file="$base_path$path"}


    {if $user_type eq 'professional'}

        {* after interview section - professional *}
        {* ******************************************** *}

        {assign  var="path" value="/views/video/video_after_interview_professional.tpl" }
        {include file="$base_path$path"}

    {elseif $user_type eq 'employer'}

        {* after interview section - employer *}
        {* ******************************************** *}

        {assign  var="path" value="/views/video/video_after_interview_employer.tpl" }
        {include file="$base_path$path"}

    {/if}

    {* Thank you page *}
    {* ******************************************** *}

    {assign  var="path" value="/views/video/video_feedback_thank_you.tpl" }
    {include file="$base_path$path"}

{else}

    {* No Interview Page *}
    {* ******************************************** *}

    {assign  var="path" value="/views/video/video_no_interview.tpl" }
    {include file="$base_path$path"}

{/if}
```

//current react js attempt
//latest attempt - getting unexpected token lang

```
return (
  <div>
    <MetaSpecific title={lang.metaData.title} description={lang.metaData.description} />
    <Intercom appID='bg69flze' custom_launcher_selector='.open_intercom' />
    <Spacers />

    {/*  check if the user has an interview upcoming in the next 30 minutes */}

    {isset($interview) ? 
      {/*  First Information Section */}
      <VideoFirstSection lang={lang} />

      <div className='row show-for-small-only' style={{height: '50px'}} />

      {/*  Interview Tips Section */}
      <VideoInterviewTips lang={lang} />

      {/*  Conference Calls Section */}
      <VideoCall lang={lang} />

      {($userType eq 'professional') ?
        <VideoAfterInterviewProfessional lang={lang} />
      : ($userType eq 'employer') ?
        <VideoAfterInterviewEmployer lang={lang} />
      }

      {/*  Thank you page */}
      <VideoFeedbackThankYou lang={lang} />
    : (
      {/*  No Interview Page */}
      <VideoNoInterview lang={lang} />
    }

  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

it's better like this:

```
<div>{this.renderLoginButton()}</div>
```

And add a method to your Component:

```
  renderLoginButton() {
    if (this.state.isLoggedIn) {
      return <LogoutButton ... />
    } else {
      return <LoginButton ... />
    }
  }
```

Also check the docs on conditional rendering https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: _ that doesn't solve my problem - its a nested if else condition -- with a parameter that doesn't appear to be getting rendered

Comment: the problem seems to be a syntax error: you have no condition before `<VideoFeedbackThankYou />`

Comment: -- if you try and render two LogoutButtons -- how would you handle that -- and give each the parameter lang

Comment: you need a wrapper... in the `return` function... everything needs to be inside a single `div` for example.

Comment: but then the token lang doesn't get recognised

Comment: this seems to be a different question, please post another one with the code updated, and better explained, so you can receive a correct answer.

Comment: "//current react js attempt //latest attempt - getting unexpected token lang"

Comment: the syntax error I mentioned is still there. You have `( : ` before `<VideoNoInterview />` without opening condition.

Comment: explain - please answer and rewrite

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
return (
    <div>
      {isLoggedIn && <LogoutButton onClick={this.handleLogoutClick} />}
      {!isLoggedIn && <LoginButton onClick={this.handleLoginClick} />}
    </div>
  );
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: _ not its too simple and its not related to my core if else nested situation

Comment: Guessing the variable isLoggedIn returns a boolean value you may procced as suggested.

Comment: -- that login thing is an example -- its not my example

Comment: it does matter - my example is far more complex

Comment: you may do that replacing the `{isLoggedIn && <LogoutButton onClick={this.handleLogoutClick} />}` for `{isLoggedIn && <whatever you like />}` and **whatever you like** can be a complex component.

Comment: --- dude - its not even my code -- if you think its so simple - take the code example I am working from and write a version with no errors

Comment: for example: you may declare a function like this: `renderSomething = () => { return ( <div> ... </div> ); }` and then you can call it from your render function like this `return ( <div> {isLoggedIn && this.renderSomething()} {!isLoggedIn && this.renderAnotherthing()} </div> );`

Comment: you said you're having troubles on conditions, right?